# Instantiating a conditional statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, pseudocode

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
> head(Data1A)
        Prime Target CorrectAnswer Accuracy   RT   Block TrialType
1     bezaaid barkme    PseudoWord        1 3450 Block 1        NA
2       hazen lemmet          Word        1 1108 Block 1        NA
3  bergtoppen slavin          Word        1 1160 Block 1        NA
4       wekte gareel          Word        1 1250 Block 1        NA
5      zessen studio          Word        1  557 Block 1        NA
6 nauwkeurige hotens    PseudoWord        1  882 Block 1        NA
```

As you can see, the column `TrialType` has to be filled, and I need a conditional statement to do it. I know what I want and I wrote in down in pseudocode as best as I could, but I am light years away of being able to implement this in the right syntax. Any help is much appreciated.

The Pseudocode:

For each cell in `Data1A$TrialType` if the corresponding cell in `Data1A$Block` is equal to `Block 2` or `Block 3` and the corresponding row in `Data1A$CorrectAnswer` is equal to `Word` OR if the corresponding cell in Data1A$Block is equal to "Block 4" or "Block 5" and the corresponding cell in `Data1A$CorrectAnswer` is equal to `PseudoWord` then the corresponding cell in `TrialType` will be equal to `Regular` else if the corresponding cell in `Data1A$Block` is equal to `Block 1` or `Block 6` OR if the corresponding cell in `Data1A$Block` is equal to  `Block 2` or  `Block3` and the corresponding row in `Data1A$CorrectAnswer` is equal to `pseudoWord` OR if the corresponding cell in `Data1A$Block` is equal to `Block 4` or `Block 5` and the corresponding cell in `Data1A$CorrectAnswer` is equal to `Word` then the corresponding cell in `Data1A$TrialType` is equal to `Random`

I hope this is understandable. I will be checking in case there are doubts regarding my intentions with the pseudocode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really get a headeach to simplify your logic here.

But This should work.

I generate some data

```
dat <- read.table(text =        "Prime Target CorrectAnswer Accuracy   RT   Block TrialType
                  1     bezaaid barkme    PseudoWord        1 3450 'Block 4'        NA
                  2       hazen lemmet          Word        1 1108 'Block 5'        NA
                  3  bergtoppen slavin          Word        1 1160 'Block 4'        NA
                  1     bezaaid barkme    PseudoWord        1 3450 'Block 5'        NA
                  2       hazen lemmet          Word        1 1108 'Block 2'        NA
                  3  bergtoppen slavin          Word        1 1160 'Block 3'        NA
                  1     bezaaid barkme    PseudoWord        1 3450 'Block 2'        NA
                  2       hazen lemmet          Word        1 1108 'Block 3'        NA
                  3  bergtoppen slavin          Word        1 1160 'Block 1'        NA
                  4       wekte gareel          Word        1 1250 'Block 6'        NA
                  5      zessen studio          Word        1  557 'Block 1'        NA
                  6 nauwkeurige hotens    PseudoWord        1  882 'Block 3'        NA",header = T,row.names = NULL)
```

Then I implement your logic:

```
transform(dat,
          TrialType= ifelse(Block %in% c('Block 4','Block 5'),
                            ifelse(CorrectAnswer =="Word" ,"Random","Regular"),
                            ifelse(Block  %in% c('Block 2','Block 3'),
                                   ifelse(CorrectAnswer =="Word" ,"Regular","Random"),
                                   'Random')))
```

Here the result

```
  row.names       Prime Target CorrectAnswer Accuracy   RT   Block TrialType
1          1     bezaaid barkme    PseudoWord        1 3450 Block 4   Regular
2          2       hazen lemmet          Word        1 1108 Block 5    Random
3          3  bergtoppen slavin          Word        1 1160 Block 4    Random
4          1     bezaaid barkme    PseudoWord        1 3450 Block 5   Regular
5          2       hazen lemmet          Word        1 1108 Block 2   Regular
6          3  bergtoppen slavin          Word        1 1160 Block 3   Regular
7          1     bezaaid barkme    PseudoWord        1 3450 Block 2    Random
8          2       hazen lemmet          Word        1 1108 Block 3   Regular
9          3  bergtoppen slavin          Word        1 1160 Block 1    Random
10         4       wekte gareel          Word        1 1250 Block 6    Random
11         5      zessen studio          Word        1  557 Block 1    Random
12         6 nauwkeurige hotens    PseudoWord        1  882 Block 3    Random
```

Comment: thanks for your help. unfortunately the code is not doing what I wanted. It is probably my fault, since I made a mistake in the pseudocode (already fixed). I mean to refer to the value of the column 'CorrectAnswer' and not to the column 'target'. Everything else remains the same. 
Still, what your code did was to assign Random to all trials from block 1, 2 and 3, and regular to all trials from block 4 and 5 (in this particular data.frame there wasn't any block 6 cells)

Comment: @Hernan_L I update my answer with a new data.frame containg more examples. Please the result and tell me which line is not correct.?

Comment: Thanks a lot @agstudy ! I just replaced 'dat' for the name of my data.frame of course, but now the code works perfectly! Many thanks for your help, you have saved me countless hours of manual work :)

Comment: @Hernan_L you can accept the answer if you are satisfied! by checking the box at left.

Comment: @Arun did you see that! Amazing how the OP can understand such logic and write in English but he can't do it using R...

Comment: Just a minor comment. To permantently modify the data.frame with the code (instead of just seeing the printed result) I redefined the data.frame as with the code from agstudy. So, it's: 
Data1A <- "agstudy's code"

Comment: @Hernan_L yes.. in my code to change the initial data.frame `dat <- transform(dat,...)`